# How do I create a WYSIWYG code editor with autocomplete to my web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, autocomplete

I'm developing a web application and I want the user to see autocomplete results like the autocomplete results shown by Eclipse.

Where should I start from?

Comment: can you explain more? Are you trying to implement an IDE environment or do you just want autocomplete for some text input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... Seems interesting. Since you want to provide an online editor, so check out this jQueryUI page ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ ). Along with this you will need knowledge of java reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you consider using Java reflection and study the Java Class class implementation, specifically the getMethods() method which should supply the foundational functionality you are looking for, see [java.lang.class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29)